# How to determine what in the new FB App iframe browser is breaking https in my App

Tags: iframe, https, facebook-iframe

https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=212108875466071

As far as I can tell, we are doing everything right, and FB's new new mini-feed App browser seems to be injecting ONE or TWO insecure resources from time to time.... NOT all the time.

How can I be positive it's FB's fault, so I can file a bug?  We are only showing broken https with the new iframe.... and most of what is being is supplied by that setup IS secure, but they have stupid little things like an insecure 'credits' ikon, which breaks the whole damn thing.

If it's our fault, I need to fix it.  If it's FB's, I need to stop wasting so much time debugging their platform for them.

Answer (score 0):

Look at chrome's javascript console, it show warnings when an insecure resource is loaded on a secure page.

[image]

See the warning before the syntax error.

See also http://googleonlinesecurity.blogspot.com/2011/06/trying-to-end-mixed-scripting.html (where this image come from).